# HTML 5 - What does <text> do?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, syntax, markdown

I'm working with a .NET Framework 4.7.2 MVC project and I'm looking this code:

```
@if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.SomeObject.Field) == false)
{
    <text>.@Model.SomeObject.Field</text>
}
```

What does `<text></text>` do? Is that valid HTML 5 or is it part of razor?

Comment: it's razor syntax so you can put plain text in between: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not HTML5 tag. It's razor syntax to write text inside code block.

[image]

> The  tag is an element that is treated specially by Razor. It
>   causes Razor to interpret the inner contents of the  block as
>   content, and to not render the containing  tag element (meaning
>   only the inner contents of the  element will be rendered – the
>   tag itself will not). This makes it convenient when you want to render
>   multi-line content blocks that are not wrapped by an HTML element.

More information in [article](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax).

Comment: "The <text> tag is an element that is treated specially by Razor. It causes Razor to interpret the inner contents of the <text> block as content, and to not render the containing <text> tag element (meaning only the inner contents of the <text> element will be rendered – the tag itself will not).  This makes it convenient when you want to render multi-line content blocks that are not wrapped by an HTML element." Excerpt from the article mentioned by @Backs

Comment: And you felt the need to post it in a comment @BernoulliIT? IMHO, the answer should have included some of this in their answer as it seems like this post is more of a comment...

Comment: Additional Question: What's the difference between using `@:` and `<text></text>`?

Comment: @KolobCanyon did you read the article?

Comment: Yep I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: With @ you can add a single line. And with <text> tag you can add a whole block of content.